# How to display a set of indexes to screen in array

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm using a List of BaseItem and I wanna show each time I press some button to show a different index range in array.

Here is an example I tried to add different items that aren't stackable.

```
Public class BaseItem
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public string descrip {get;set;}
    public bool isStackable {get;set;}
    public int stackSize {get;set;}
    public int maxStackSize {get;set;}
    public Texture2D texure{get;set}
}
```

I used this part of code that I found on this site by searching.

```
Vector2 Pos;
int ItemsPerPage = 6;
int Columns = 1;
int Rows = 255;
int CurrentPage = 1;
int MaxPages;
BaseItem[,] items = new Baseitem[Columns,Rows];

public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{

       for(int X = 0; i < Columns; X ++)
       {
          for(int X = 0; i < Columns; X ++)
          {
              int DrawX = Pos.X +(X * (slothSize +2);
              int DrawY = Pos.Y +(Y * (slothSize +2);
              spriteBatch.Draw(items[X,Y].texure, new Rectangle(DrawX, DrawY, 32,32), Color.Whie);
          }

       }

}
```

My problem, how do I show 6 items per page, so the extra items will be moved to next page,

so if I have 30 items I wound need to have 5 pages that all have 6 items.

My main question is how to set and move pages 1 by 1 and show on each page x amount of items using `var itemsPerPage.`

So basically moving extra items on extra pages and adding number var maxpages based on  `itemes.length / ItemsPerPage = maxPages`

What I have tried using 1D array
Also I can't draw more items at the time. They all drawn on same position.
If I use For loop 2 times...making it X and Y pos....it wont Draw.
Here is an example:

```
BaseItem items[,] = new BaseItem[] {} 


public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
     var result = Items.Cast<double>().Skip(ItemsPerPage * Currentpage).Take(itemsPerPage);
    foreach(item in result)
    {
        for(int X = 0; X < Columns; X++)
        {
            for(int Y = 0;Y < Rows; Y++)
             { 
                 int DrawX = pos.X + (X * (SlowtWidth +2);
                 int DrawY = pos.Y + (Y * (SlowtWidth +2);
                 if(items[X,Y] != null)
                 {
                      spriteBatch.Draw(items[X,Y], new Rectangle(DrawX,DrawY,SlotWidth, SlotHeight) new Rectangle(0,0,SlotWidth, SlotHeight),Color.White)  
                 }
             {
        {
    }
}

public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if(CurrentPage <= 0)
    {
       CurrentPage = MaxPages;
    }

    if(CurrentPage => MaxPages)
    {
       CurrentPage = 1;
    }
    if(Input.KeyPressed(Keys.A))
    { 
        CurrentPage++;
    {
    if(Input.KeyPressed(Keys.D))
    { 
        CurrentPage--;
    {
    Input.Update(gameTime)
}
```

Now it wont Draw items to a screen at all...if I just replace result with items(list) it will draw but not cap the list with `ItemsPerPage`

I can set number of "slots" by using `columns and rows` but how can I change page...aka skip a numbers in array and show next index...somethingh like for 1D array `.skip(20).take(29)` bud done in 2D array?

Comment: Where is the concept of a "page" in your code? It should be simple, something like this: `spriteBatch.Draw(...); DrawPage(pageNumber); numDrawnOnThisPage++; if (numDrawnOnThisPage == 6) { pageNumber++; numDrawnOnThisPage = 0; }`.

Comment: I was thinking as `MaxPages = math.celling(items.length / ItemsPerPage);` 
So when i press some button it uses CurrentPage as  value to change page and Display x amount per page.
So i need help with this litle problem.

Comment: Do you need to calculate a `MaxPages`? Why not just draw items 6 at a time per page until you run out of items. If you want to know the number of pages you could just count them as you create them. But yes you can calculate it, your `Math.Ceiling()` will work but you need to cast at least one of the arguments to float first or else the integer division will truncate the result first: `Math.Ceiling((float)items.Length / ItemsPerPage)` should work.

Comment: How to set how many items can be drawn at time.
If i say 6...and page is2...it will need to draw from 5 to 11 and so on.
How do i set maxitems per page?

Comment: So basically wanna draw from 0 to 5 on page 1, page 2 from 6 to 11 and so on. And when i reduce/increase  value in `Currentpage` by 1 draw that set of index in that array.

Comment: I don't see the concept of "Page" in your code. Until you add that I don't know how to answer your questions or help you. As far as I can see you only have 1 "page" which is apparently `spriteBatch` I guess. Show me the code for how you can draw things on 2 different pages and I can show you how to only draw 6 things on each of those pages. Currently you have no code at all to draw a "second page" as far as I can tell, let alone 5 pages for 30 items.

Comment: I do not know how to use skip on 2D arrray.
On 1D array aka `Items[] items  = new ltems[]{};

`var result = items.Skip(ItemsPerPage * CurrentPage).Take(ItemsPerPage);`

this is for 1D array...but how to do with 2d or 3D array is making me puzzling. Since i can't do `skip.take `for` items[,]`

Answer (score 0):

In your Draw method you've got two Rectangles: first with DrawX and DrawY set as position and second with 0,0. I think, you could use second one instead of first.

Comment: I did that but i got error `foreach(item in result)` Erorr was pointing at in part;
I didn't now make instance of that...

Comment: First 2 params are X and Y pos, seconds are Wight and height of object.

for both Rectangls...you mean i replace for first 0,0.sw, sh and second DrawX,DrawY, Sw,sh

Sw = slotwidth, sh= slotheight?

Comment: When i casted as 2D array as double in `foreach(item in result)`

Comment: before foreach loop `var result = items.Cast<double>().Skip(3).Take(1)` i can't see inside of foreah loop item.texture or such.
I still use items[X,Y].Textrue....and itmes are still drawing more than `ItemsPerPage = 3 ` says

Comment: this answer dose not help.